# User Agent login device

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am working on PWA and need to figure out whether the user is accessing through IOS or Android or Desktop.

This is to be done as according to the user we will be showing the particular URL to the user.

So, how can we figure out this?

Comment: Better add more information on what you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

You could check and parse the `User-Agent` HTTP header?

It feels quite the normal thing to do according to the title of your question.

Answer (score 0):

Basically User Agent doesn't allow you to be 100% sure that user uses exactly that browser, but for 90% of cases it works pretty well.

I'd suggest you to consider using a library like [sniff-fns](https://github.com/js-fns-incubator/sniff-fns) or any other similar, so there covered most of the cases